# Scraping Image URLs with beautifusoup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, jupyter

Trying to learn something today and doing a bit of scraping.

I am trying to list product names and corresponding image URLs into a spreadsheet.

I managed to store the names but the images don't seem to work. Hopefully you can help!

Here is the code I use for extracting the text:

```
results[0].find('p', {'class': 'product-card__name'}).get_text()
```

Here is what I thought would extract the image:

```
results[0].find('img', {'class':'product-card__image'}).get_src()
```

This is obvioulsy not working.Returning that "'NoneType' object is not callable"

Any pointers?

For reference, below is the source I am trying to scrape.

```
<li class="product-grid__item"><a href="/p/63818/bumbu-the-original-rum-glass-pack" class="product-card" title=" Bumbu The Original Rum Glass Pack" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Products-GridView', 'click', '63818 : Bumbu The Original Rum / Glass Pack'])"><div class="product-card__image-container"><img src="https://img.thewhiskyexchange.com/480/rum_bum4.jpg" alt="Bumbu The Original Rum Glass Pack" class="product-card__image" loading="lazy" width="3" height="4"></div><div class="product-card__content"><p class="product-card__name"> Bumbu The Original Rum<span class="product-card__name-secondary">Glass Pack</span></p><p class="product-card__meta"> 70cl / 40% </p></div><div class="product-card__data"><p class="product-card__price"> £39.95 </p><p class="product-card__unit-price"> (£57.07 per litre) </p></div></a></li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grab the image url, you have to call `.get('src')` instead of `.get_src()`

```
results[0].find('img', {'class':'product-card__image'}).get('src')
```

**Example:**

```
html='''
<li class="product-grid__item">
 <a class="product-card" href="/p/63818/bumbu-the-original-rum-glass-pack" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'Products-GridView', 'click', '63818 : Bumbu The Original Rum / Glass Pack'])" title=" Bumbu The Original Rum Glass Pack">
  <div class="product-card__image-container">
   <img alt="Bumbu The Original Rum Glass Pack" class="product-card__image" height="4" loading="lazy" src="https://img.thewhiskyexchange.com/480/rum_bum4.jpg" width="3"/>
  </div>
  <div class="product-card__content">
   <p class="product-card__name">
    Bumbu The Original Rum
    <span class="product-card__name-secondary">
     Glass Pack
    </span>
   </p>
   <p class="product-card__meta">
    70cl / 40%
   </p>
  </div>
  <div class="product-card__data">
   <p class="product-card__price">
    £39.95
   </p>
   <p class="product-card__unit-price">
    (£57.07 per litre)
   </p>
  </div>
 </a>
</li>
'''

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
#print(soup.prettify())
print(soup.find('img', {'class':'product-card__image'}).get('src'))
```

**Output:**

```
https://img.thewhiskyexchange.com/480/rum_bum4.jpg
```